# how to deploy these two endpoints in CXF so both work

Tags: cxf

I have the following code and whichever service is created last works(so my annotations must be correct).  I am assuming this must be a copy the example mistake but I am not sure how to deploy two endpoints without them conflicting.  Here is the code I was using to deploy both of them...

```
public void start() {
    Server svr3 = createRestService(restEnrollmentResponse);
    Server svr2 = createRestService(restEnrollment);

}

public static Server createRestService(Object service) {
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    sf.setResourceClasses(service.getClass());
    sf.setResourceProvider(service.getClass(), new SingletonResourceProvider(service));
    sf.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:9900/");
    Server svr = sf.create();
    return svr;
}
```

NOTE: The restEnrollment @Path is /enrollment and the restEnrollmentResponse @Path is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this nightmare out.  Change both @Path annotations to @Path("/") and then change the

sf.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:9900/");

to

sf.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:9900/enrollmentrequest");

sf.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:9900/othercontext");

and it now works ;).

Dean

Comment: So you need to set difference addresses for different REST services?